# Filter for first day of every year in R tidy verse

Tags: r, tidyverse

The data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(lubridate)

df <- tq_get("^GSPC", from='1930-01-01', to='2022-12-31')
```

I want to filter for the first date of every year.

My code:

```
df %>% filter(month(date) == 1, day(date) == 1) %>% head(n=Inf)
```

**I get the following message:**

> A tibble: 0 x 8 … with 8 variables: symbol , date , open
> , high , low , close ,    volume , adjusted
>  Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

If I use any other number than 1 in `day(date) == 1` the code works.

This code works:
`df %>% filter(month(date) == 1, day(date) == 2) %>% head(n=Inf)`

Question:

Why is `day(date) == 1` not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% with(month(date) == 1 & day(date) == 1) %>% any()
> [1] FALSE
```

This result shows that there isn't any observation for january first in your dataset, thus `filter` always returns an empty tibble. The problem is with your data, not the code.

Another way to check it:

```
df$date %>% paste() %>% grepl("[0-9]{4}-01-01", .) %>% any()
> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Not possible to delete it. "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."